# Add a pattern repeated image as a background of another image using ImageMagick convert

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to add a pattern repeated image as the background of another image that has spaces around. For example i have the pattern 200x200 and an image 1200x800. I have accomplished to add a background color.

The command i'm using to add a background color

```
convert -background "#333" -resize 768x450 -gravity Center -extent 768x450
```

Now i need to add a pattern instead of that color. Some suggest that i should make the pattern as one image with the maximum size then use it to add it as background image.

Is it possible to do it with `convert` or any other command using **ImageMagick** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but I am guessing it's this. Let's make a 200x200 tile to start off with:

```
convert -size 200x200 radial-gradient:red-blue t200x200.png
```

[image]

And now you want to make a 1200x800 image by tiling that basic unit:

```
convert -size 1200x800 tile:t200x200.png BigBoy.png
```

[image]

If you now want to overlay a fine-art, high-quality, centred portrait over the top of your harmonious, subtle background, you can do this:

```
convert -size 1200x800 tile:t200x200.png -gravity center smiley.gif -composite BigBoy.png
```

[image]